# Windows phone map keeps crashing

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, freeze

I am creating a phone application that maps out your position as well as other assets. The phone gets updates on the position of the other assets over WI-FI, and on a set time that the user picks - normally 5 seconds. The problems that the phone will freeze anywhere around 4 minutes. What can I do to fix it?

This is my code:

```
    public bool CenterOnUser { get; set; }

    public MapView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CenterOnUser = false;
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _continue = true;

        mapBing.Children.Add(_mapLayer);

        _time = Convert.ToInt32(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["time"]);

        _thread = new Thread(Update) {Name = "Map Update"};
        _thread.Start();

        foreach (var asset in DataManager.GetPhoneAssetDictionary())
        {
            _averageLatitude += double.Parse(asset.Value.Latitude);
            _averageLongitude += double.Parse(asset.Value.Longitude);
        }

        _averageLatitude /= DataManager.GetPhoneAssetDictionary().Count;
        _averageLongitude /= DataManager.GetPhoneAssetDictionary().Count;

        mapBing.Center = new GeoCoordinate(_averageLatitude, _averageLongitude);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        while (_thread.IsAlive && _continue)
        {
            _mapLayer.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
            {
                foreach (var asset in DataManager.GetPhoneAssetDictionary())
                {
                    _position = new GetPhoneGPS().Positions();

                    //  Find out if we already have a pin on the map for this asset
                    var pin = _mapLayer.Children.Cast<Pushpin>().FirstOrDefault(assetPin => assetPin.Tag.ToString() == asset.Key);

                    if (pin == null) // do we have a pin
                    {
                        //  We don't yet.  Create one
                        pin = new Pushpin {Tag = asset.Key};

                        //  Figure out the name to give the pin
                        if (asset.Key == _position.UniqueId)
                        {
                            pin.Content = "You are here";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pin.Content = String.IsNullOrEmpty(asset.Value.Name) ? asset.Key : asset.Value.Name;
                        }

                        //  Add the pin for this asset to the map
                        _mapLayer.Children.Add(pin);
                    }

                    //  Always update the pin location
                    pin.Location = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(asset.Value.Latitude), double.Parse(asset.Value.Longitude));
                }
            });
            Thread.Sleep(_time * 1000);
        }
    }

    private void CenterOnUserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CenterOnUser = true;
        mapBing.Center = new GeoCoordinate(double.Parse(_position.Latitude), double.Parse(_position.Longitude));
        mapBing.ZoomLevel = 15;
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mapBing.Children.Remove(_mapLayer);
        _continue = false;
        _thread.Join();
    }
}
```

I am a novice at Threading, and I believe that might be the problem. Thank you for any help.

This is the code for the getPhone.

```
    public class GetPhoneGPS : IDisposable
    {
        private static readonly Positions Position = new Positions();
        readonly GeoCoordinateWatcher _watch = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        private void UpdatePhonePosition()
        {
            _watch.MovementThreshold = 1;
            _watch.Start();
            _watch.PositionChanged += GeoPositionChange;
            var position = _watch.Position;

            //loads phones gps coordinates
            if (!position.Location.IsUnknown)
            {
                Position.Latitude = position.Location.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Longitude = position.Location.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Altitude = position.Location.Altitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Speed = position.Location.Speed.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            Position.Date = DateTime.Now;
            Position.Name = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["username"].ToString();
            Position.UniqueId = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["UniqueId"].ToString();
        }

        private void GeoPositionChange(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            var position = e.Position;

            //loads phones gps coordinates
            if (!position.Location.IsUnknown)
            {
                Position.Latitude = position.Location.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Longitude = position.Location.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Altitude = position.Location.Altitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Position.Speed = position.Location.Speed.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            Position.Date = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public Positions Positions()
        {
            UpdatePhonePosition();
            return Position;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _watch.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's "GetPhoneGPS()" ?  Maybe that's what's causing the crash ?  Pop the full source up.

Answer (score 0):

Is this when you are using it through the emulator or once you've released the app in dev mode to the phone? I've found there are some instances where the emulator doesn't like updating but they are few and far between.

Looking at things it all seems to be okay - so long as the phone has moved the code will execute; I use practically the same logic with my apps.

Comment: That was on the emulator,  but I'll test it out on a phone to make sure.

Comment: I put the program on the phone and it caused the phone to crash a few seconds after the map came up